# showing fifth post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

in my wordpress website how can start showing posts from fifth post?
Because in top of my website there is a slide show that shows title of first five posts
and again under slide show shows first five posts and it is not beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either **get_posts** or **query_posts** as a means to show the most recent posts excluding the first five. Please keep in mind query_posts directly alters the main loop by changing the variables of the global variable $wp_query.

This kind of seems like what you want though so an example would be to modify the index file of your theme to include:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&offset=5');
```

*Note:* You can change the posts_per_page to what ever you desire. You also have many more options available to you.

For more detailed information please see the following documentation :

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

***TLDR:*** Use the offset parameter in WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with PHP this code will solve your problem.
Setup a logic to not show data for first 5 post as follows:

```
$i = 0;
while (have_posts()) {  
     ++$i;   
     if ($i > 5) {
         the_title(); 
         // and more content
     }
}
```

This will show data inside loop only if `$i > 5`.